# Fund. system of neighborhoods/ Openness of set in topological space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X\neq\emptyset$ be a set and let $\mathfrak{B}_x$ be the fundamental system of neighborhoods of $x\in X$. The collection
$$\tau = \left\lbrace U\in\tau : (\forall x\in U)(\exists B_x\in\mathfrak{B}_x)(B_x\subset U)\right\rbrace $$
is a topology on $X$. Given the properties:

(1) $B_x\in\mathfrak{B}_x\Longrightarrow x\in B_x$
(2) $B^1_x,B^2_x\in\mathfrak{B}_x\Longrightarrow \exists B^3_x\in\mathfrak{B}_x : B^3_x\subset B^1_x\cap B^2_x$
(3) $B_x\in\mathfrak{B}_x\Longrightarrow\exists B^1_x\in\mathfrak{B}_x : B^1_x\subset B_x$ and  $\forall y\in B^1_x : \exists B_y\in\mathfrak{B}_y : B_y\subset B_x$

Fix $x\in X$

> Show that $V := \left\lbrace z\in B_x : (\exists B_z\in\mathfrak{B}_z)(B_z\subset B_x) \right\rbrace$ is $\tau$-open.

**Attempt**
Because $B_x\subset B_x$, we have $x\in V$ hence $V\neq\emptyset$. Let $z\in V$, to show $V\in\tau $, we must find $B_z\subset V$.

*I can't see any direct way to do this. For instance, there is no reason for any intersection of the sets $B_z$ to be wholly contained in $V$*

Assume for a contradiction than $V\notin\tau$, then there exists $z\in V$ such that for any $B_z\in\mathfrak{B}_z$ $B_z\not\subset V$

*Again, seems fruitless*

What I can say is that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists some $B\subset \bigcap_{j=1}^n B^j_z$ per property (2). So, I could construct:
$$B_z\supset B^1_z\supset\ldots\supset B^m_z\supset B^{m+1}_z\supset\ldots  $$
And per our assumption all of these $B^j_z\not\subset V$.

What I can't say, what happens as $m\to\infty$.

Right now, I am hoping to arrive at $z\notin V$ which would be a contradiction.

What can we do to make progress? Can we prove it directly?

Comment: OP, let me know if my answer satisfies you. If not, perhaps you can indicate how my interpretation of your question diverges from your intention, and I will try to amend it accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand the question, however I will attempt to answer it as best I can, namely, I will answer the following question, which is my interpretation of OP's question.

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. For every $x \in X$, let $\mathfrak{B}_x$ be a [neighborhood basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_system#Basis) of $x$. Let $x \in X$, and let $N$ be a neighborhood of $x$. Define
>    $$
>  V := \left\{z \in N\ |\!:\ \exists B \in \mathfrak{B}_z,\ B \subseteq N\right\}.
>  $$
>    Show that $V \in \tau$.

***Proof***

For every $z \in V$ denote by $B_z$ a member of $\mathfrak{B}_z$ such that $B_z \subseteq N$, and denote by $G_z$ an open set such that $z \in G_z \subseteq B_z$. It suffices to show that
$$
V = \bigcup_{z \in V} G_z.
$$

To see that $V \subseteq \cup_{z \in V} G_z$, let $z^* \in V$, and observe that $z^* \in G_{z^*} \subseteq \cup_{z \in V} G_z$.

To see that $V \supseteq \cup_{z \in V} G_z$, let $z \in V$, and observe that $z \in G_z \subseteq B_z \subseteq N$. Since $B_z \in \mathfrak{B}_z$, this shows that $z \in V$.

Q.E.D.

Comment: @Eevan Aad Why does there necessarely exist $G_z\in\tau$ such that $G_z\subset B_z$? If $G_z\in\tau$ is such that contains $z$, then it's automatically a neighborhood. That I agree with. The question now becomes: If $B_z$ is basis element, does it necessarely contain an open set $G_z\ni z$

Comment: @AlvinLepik: $B_z$ is a member of $\mathfrak{B}_z$, which is, by definition, a neighborhood basis of $z$. As such, each member of $\mathfrak{B}_z$ is a neighborhood of $z$. In particular, $B_z$ is a neighborhood of $z$. By the definition of [a neighborhood of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)#Neighbourhood_of_a_point), $B_z$ includes an open set containing $z$.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: Are you satisfied with my answer? If so, I'd appreciate it if you click the check mark next to it. If not, could you please indicate what is missing? I will do my best to amend my answer to meet your requirements.

Comment: I am working through the steps, though, at quick glance, things seem to be in order. You answered my question in a more general setting.

Comment: OK. Thanks for accepting my answer. If you need any more help coming to terms with it, please let me know.